# Understanding the function argument for .filter()

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry for such a basic question. Can anyone explain exactly how this function works as an argument inside of `.filter()`?

I've tried using several times but it doesn't always return what I expect. For example:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="">This is a link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="" rel="bs">This is a link</a></li>
</ul>
```

-

```
$(document).click(function(){
    $("ul li a").filter(function(){
        return $(this).eq(2); // selects every a
    }).before("String");    
});
```

Still selects every `a`  - same with `return $("ul li a").eq(2)` - I don't understand this.

Does this function **have** to return something? Can someone please explain how this works and its limitations? Thanks.

Comment: What is `$(this).eq(2)` supposed to do?  What is your criteria?  Which elements do you want to filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant sentence [from the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) that will help you understand the `filter()` function's callback function is this:

> The second form of this method allows us to filter elements against a function rather than a selector. For each element, if the function returns true (or a "truthy" value), the element will be included in the filtered set; otherwise, it will be excluded.

Basically, when the callback function you supply returns a non "falsy" value, that value is added to the resulting jQuery object.

The test you are using is `$(this).eq(2)` - if the result of that command does not evaluate to false, it will be added to the resulting jQuery object.

---

Lets take this code as an example:

```
if ( $("#non_existant_element") ){
  console.log("truthy value!");
}
```

You can see from the selector that the element doesn't really exist - but you'll still see the `console.log` because an empty jQuery object does not evaluate to "false".

Answer (score 2):

`.filter()` calls the passed function for each element.  If the function returns a "truthy" value, then it's kept in the set.  If it returns a "falsy" value, then it's removed.

```
$(this).eq(2);
```

This will return a jQuery object.  Whether or not it contains anything is a different story, but a jQuery object (even an empty one) is "truthy".  So this will return you every element.

Answer (score 2):

Basically `.filter()` with a parameter as function will iterate through all the elements that are currently being selected, and the return inside that function will decide that whether to keep that particular element or to skip it. In your case `....eq(2)` will always return some object, so in that case it will consider that as true and keep all the elements and return those elements accordingly.